# if $2017 \mid\sum_{i=1}^{1000}x^k_{i}$,show $2017 \mid x_{i},\forall i=1,2,\ldots,1000$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

Let $x_{i}(i=1,2,\ldots,1000)$ be integers,and for all postive integers  $k\le 672$,such $$2017 \mid\sum_{i=1}^{1000}x^k_{i}$$

show that
$$2017 \mid x_{i},\forall i=1,2,\ldots,1000$$

maybe is use [Newton's identities](https://brilliant.org/wiki/newtons-identities/) to solve it? I remember this is old problem for any prime number $p=2017$  .
But I can't solve it

Answer (score 0):

**Notations, discussion, restatement:**

Let $p$ be the prime $2017$.

Let $N=1000$, $n=672$ to have a simpler notation, e.g. when using indices.
We also introduce $m=N-n=328$.

We will work over the finite field $F=\Bbb F_p$ 
with $p$ elements instead of $\Bbb Z$, by passing once for all times from the given $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$
to their images in $F$ via the modulo $p$ map $\Bbb Z\to\Bbb F_p$, and use by a slight abuse of notation 
the same notations $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N$ for the images. Let $x$ be the compound tuple / variable $x=(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_N)$.

If i correctly understand the OP, we have
$$
p_1(x)=p_2(x)=\dots=p_n(x)=0\ ,
$$
where $p_k=p_k(X)$ is the $k$.th (symmetric) Newton polynomial in the multiple variable $X$, 
$$ p_k(X)=\sum_{1\le j\le N}X_j^k\ .$$
Let $e_1,e_2,\dots,e_n$ be the (symmetric) elementary polynomials of degree, respectively, $1,2,\dots,n$.
Let us set $e_0=1$.
There is a linear relation (linked in the OP) relating 
$$ke_k\text{ with }e_0p_k,\ e_1p_{k-1},\ \dots,\ e_{k-1}p_1$$
in the polynomial ring. (It is the sum of these products.) Conversely, each symmetric polynomial of 
degree $k$ (e.g. $p_k$) can be written as a polynomial in the elementary polynomials (of homogenous weighted degree $k$)
so the given relations are *equivalent* to 
$$e_1(x)=e_2(x)=\dots=e_n(x)=0\ .$$ 
(The factor $k$ of $ke_k$, considered in $F=\Bbb F_p$, $1\le k\le n<p$,
does not vanish.)

This is further equivalent to the relation
$$
\prod_{1\le j\le n}(X+x_j)
=
X^N + \underbrace{e_{n+1}(x)X^{N-n-1}+\dots+e_N(x)}_{P(X)}\ ,
$$
where $P$ is a polynomial of degree $<N-n=m$.

So we have to show that there is no polynomial of the shape $X^N+P(X)$, $\deg P<N-n=m$, which splits
as a product of linear factors over $F=\Bbb F_p$.

**Intermezzo:**

To get a feeling about the choice of the special values of $p,N,n$, let us give a
counterexample for "similar, slightly changed values". In $F$ we have a split of $X^p-X$ in linear factors.
In particular, every factor of $X^{p-1}-1$ splits linearly over $F$.
In particular for every $d$ divisor of $p-1$ the polynomial $X^d-1$ splits linearly over $F$.
In our case, here are the divisors of $p-1=2016$ between $100$ and $1000$, sage code:

```
sage: [ d for d in 2016.divisors() if 100 < d < 1000 ]
[112, 126, 144, 168, 224, 252, 288, 336, 504, 672]
```

So $d=672$ is in the list.
Then $X^{1000-672}\;\Big(X^{672}-1\Big)$ splits linearly in $F$.
This is a counterexample for the case with the last Newton polynomial equation removed, i.e.
the case with $671$ taken instead of $n=672$.
There is a thin air difference between the counterexample values and the OP values, but a major one, and this should 
show up in the argumentation.
So let us go on.

> How many multiple (i.e. double, triple, a.s.o.) roots can be there for the (sparse, "sedimentary") polynomial
>   $$ G = X^N+P(X)$$ as above?

**Proof:**

Any multiple root of $G$ survives as root of the derivative, which is $NX^{N-1}+P'(X)$, 
so it is the root of the polynomial $NP-XP'$ of degree $<(N-n)$, i.e. of degree $\le (N-n-1)$.
**We assume now $P\ne 0$.** (And search for a **contradiction** in the sequel. The case $P=0$ corresponds exactly to
the case when all components of $x$ are zero, this is what we need to prove.)

Then the leading coefficient of $(NP-XP')$ occurs in the same degree as the one for $P$, i.e. it is a non-zero
polynomial with degree between $0$ and $(n+1)$.
So $X^N+P$ has at least $N-(N-n-1)=(n+1)$ different roots.

We come back to the special values. So far we know that the polynomials
$$
\begin{aligned}
F &= X^{2016}-1\ ,\\
G &= X^{1000}+P
\end{aligned}
$$
have at least $n=(n+1)-1=672$ common roots. (The zero is not a root for $F$, but it may be for $G$. We subtracted this 
one case from the $(n+1)$ above.)
Consider now the polynomial
$$
F-X^{16}\Big(X^{1000}-P\Big)G
=X^{16}\, P^2-1\ .
$$
It shares also the common mentioned $n=672$ (non-zero) different roots with $F$ and $G$, and it has degree
$$\le 16+2\cdot 327=670\ .$$

**Contradiction.**

The assumption $P\ne 0$ is thus absurd. We have proven by contraposition $P=0$, i.e. $x=0$ (i.e. all its $N=1000$ components
vanish in $F=\Bbb F_p=\Bbb F_{2017}$).

$\square$